# Check Paypal Purchase is Success or Not in Easy Digital Download Plugin

Tags: plugin-development, e-commerce, paypal

I trying to do something for every purchase of corresponding product in easy digital download.
Let say i need to add the auto random discount code for every purchase made in easy digital download.
I tried with different hooks. But still i didn't get the correct callback on success process of paypal.
Let i make it alert on success callback of paypal.

what i am trying is something like this

```
if($paypal == 'success') {
//do something
} else {
//do something
}
function pw_edd_on_complete_purchase($payment_id) {

    // Basic payment meta
    $payment_meta = edd_get_payment_meta($payment_id);
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        alert("this is for payment");
    </script>
    <?php

    // Cart details
    //$cart_items = edd_get_payment_meta_cart_details($payment_id);

    // do something with payment data here
}

add_action('edd_complete_purchase', 'pw_edd_on_complete_purchase');
```

But i am not sure how to do this. I have the product which name as gift card let say $5.
If the user purchased this gift card then he/she get the random code of discount for purchasing some other product in future. 
Can anyone tell me which hook is achieving the above criteria ?

Any Suggestion would be great thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to generate discount codes within your callback function by using the `edd_add_discount()` function. You can learn more about this function [here on the EDD Codex](https://easydigitaldownloads.com/codex/source-function-edd_add_discount.html#15-41) to see what specific data you need to pass to the function.

However, `edd_complete_purchase` might not be the right action to hook to. If you *only* want specific codes to be generated when specific payment types (PayPal) are successfully charged, you might want to instead hook to `edd_before_payment_status_change`. This is called in `edd_update_payment_status()`, which you can also see on the EDD Codex [here](https://easydigitaldownloads.com/codex/source-function-edd_update_payment_status.html#232-262), and should let you only run `edd_add_discount()` if the `$new_status` within `edd_update_payment_status()` is `'published'` (or otherwise for a successful payment, instead of `'failed'` or `'pending'`).

Comment: If you want to use the edd_complete_purchase hook, you could check the gateway that was used by pulling it from the payment meta so that your action only fires for PayPal payments.